# Session in codeigniter is not working after moving site from live server to localhost with https set environment

Tags: codeigniter

On server session was working properly but when we set site on localhost with set https environment  Session is not working in Codeigniter. Please help

Comment: Edit your question with session config settings. Cannot guess

Comment: $config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'cisession';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 1209600;       //durée des session au max de celle de wp, soit 14j
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 30000;
;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;

Comment: $config['cookie_prefix'] = 'idvitae_';
$config['cookie_domain'] = '.idvitae.org';
$config['cookie_path']  = '/';
$config['cookie_secure'] = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;

Comment: Click on the edit button below tags and add code there rather than comment

Comment: I also found the solution I moved to dabien pc and session is working on local This is the issue on ubuntu pc